What are the points to note in a spring+block system?


This is the solution to a question related to spring+block system, and I have some doubts regarding the concept behind this question

The solution reads


The velocity of the block increases till the spring acquires it's natural length.

But the spring is not attached to the block, so when we push a block against a spring, the spring is going to elongate sending the block flying away in a constant velocity. So why do we need to know about the velocity it attains at it's natural length?

Why are they assuming $x$? What role does that play here? Do they mean that when the spring elongates to $x$, the block leaves the spring with velocity $v$?

I can understand the calculation part, but I need the concept clarification because I keep making mistakes in these type of questions

The tip of a spring accelerates toward its natural length when free to move - if it's compressed, it will lengthen, if it's stretched, it will contract.
After the spring is compressed and released, the block and spring tip accelerate to the right. The spring reaches its natural length, at which point it applies zero force. The spring tip then begins to decelerate as it moves beyond its natural length, as the spring force points to the left. The block isn't attached to the spring, though, so the spring tip decelerates but the block does not. The block's final constant speed is reached at the point where the spring reaches its natural length.

Ohhh now I get it... Thank you so much
